# Best approach for combining and grouping javascript objects by a parameter

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a shopping cart page in React, and essentially I need to group my order by product name and include a quantity.

So... if my products array is as followed...

```
const items = [
  { title: 'Test', price: 1 },
  { title: 'Test', price: 1 },
  { title: 'Another Test', price: 3 },
]
```

I'm attempting to get something like...

```
const expected = [
  { title: 'Test', price: 1, quantity: 2 },
  { title: 'Another Test', price: 3, quantity: 1 },
]
```

I've tried a few different approaches which didn't quite get me there, including using groupBy from underscorejs, but no joy!

Here's a JS fiddle I was messing around with: https://jsfiddle.net/rL8y3Lh4/2/

Comment: Title should be unique?

Comment: @Smiranin Why's that? Becuase he doesn't have an id? otherwise idk why the title would have to be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for grouping.

```js
var items = [{ title: 'Test', price: 1 }, { title: 'Test', price: 1 }, { title: 'Another Test', price: 3 }],
    grouped = items.reduce((map => (r, a) => {
        if (!map.has(a.title)) {
            map.set(a.title, { title: a.title, price: a.price, quantity: 0 });
            r.push(map.get(a.title));
        }
        map.get(a.title).quantity++;
        return r;
    })(new Map), []);

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES5 with a closure over a hash table.

```js
var items = [{ title: 'Test', price: 1 }, { title: 'Test', price: 1 }, { title: 'Another Test', price: 3 }],
    grouped = items.reduce(function (hash) {
        return function (r, a) {
            if (!hash[a.title]) {
                hash[a.title] = { title: a.title, price: a.price, quantity: 0 };
                r.push(hash[a.title]);
            }
            hash[a.title].quantity++;
            return r;
        };
    }(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much! Love the use of a Map

Answer (score 1):

In plain javascript you can do this with `reduce()`.

```js
const items = [
  { title: 'Test', price: 1 },
  { title: 'Test', price: 1 },
  { title: 'Another Test', price: 3 }
]

var o = {}
var result = items.reduce(function(r, e) {
  if (!o[e.title]) {
    o[e.title] = e;
    o[e.title].quantity = 0;
    r.push(o[e.title])
  }
  o[e.title].quantity += 1;
  return r;
}, [])
console.log(result)
```

You can also use `forEach()` and `Object.assign()` to create new object if you want to save original data.

```js
const items = [
  { title: 'Test', price: 1 },
  { title: 'Test', price: 1 },
  { title: 'Another Test', price: 3 },
]


var result = []
items.forEach(function(e) {
  if (!this[e.title]) {
    this[e.title] = Object.assign({}, e, {quantity: 0})
    result.push(this[e.title])
  }
  this[e.title].quantity += 1
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I would use `if( ! Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, e.title)) {` since it otherwise will break if the title is `toString`, `toValue` or any other name that is on the property chain of Object.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary by product name/title/ID. Loop over each item, adding a new entry or incrementing the `quantity` of an existing one:

```js
const items = [
  { title: 'Test', price: 1 },
  { title: 'Test', price: 1 },
  { title: 'Another Test', price: 3 }
];

let cart = {};
items.forEach(item => {
  if (cart[item.title]) {
    cart[item.title].quantity++;
  } else {
    cart[item.title] = {price: item.price, quantity: 1};
  }
});

console.log(cart);
```

This assumes that items with identical `title`s have identical `price`s.

Answer (score 1):

Another *short* version of applying `Array.prototype.reduce` function:

```js
var items = [{ title: 'Test', price: 1 },{ title: 'Test', price: 1 },{ title: 'Another Test', price: 3 }],    
    expected = [];

items.reduce(function (o, a) {  // grouping objects by 'title' attribute
  (o[a.title])? 
    ++o[a.title].quantity 
    : o[a.title] = expected[expected.push({title: a.title, price: a.price, quantity: 1}) - 1];
  return o;
}, {});

console.log(expected);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use lodash library in your project I would recommend lodash `unionBy`

```js
const items = [
      { title: 'Test', price: 1 },
      { title: 'Test', price: 1 },
      { title: 'Another Test', price: 3 },
    ]; 
  
  let items1 = _.map(items, function(o) {
    o.quantity = 1;
    return o;
  });

  result = _.unionWith(items1, function(a,b) {
  if(a.title === b.title) {
    b.quantity++;
  return true;
  }
  return false;  
  });

  console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this is what you have needed